# Android studio UI initilization failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i was downloading Android Studio, i first uninstall all of my JDK, and run the installer and then download the latest JDK, i also added the JDK to my system variables, i tried running the android studio
this error code comes out

```
com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: UI initialization failed
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$15(StartupUtil.java:268)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:791)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x978d141) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x978d141
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:787)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x978d141) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x978d141
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$22(StartupUtil.java:504)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:783)
    ... 14 more

-----
Your JRE: 16.0.2+7-67 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2
```

and this

```
!bootstrap.error.message.internal.error.please.refer.to.0!https://code.google.com/p/android/issues!

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x978d141) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x978d141
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.start(StartupUtil.java:301)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:140)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:83)

-----
!bootstrap.error.message.jre.details!16.0.2+7-67 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
```

my JRE version is as mentioned above

> Your JRE: 16.0.2+7-67 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2

im still trying to fix it

Comment: Let me see your source code

Comment: can you specify which source code, thanks

Comment: If you can, let me see all of them otherwise your launch activity(both logic and xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download JDK 11 instead of JDK 19, Android Studio isn't supported on JDK 19 yet